# Signal Loss over Length

Tags: wireless-networking

This is in regards to coaxial cable...

I'm looking at low loss Cable to run a wireless receiving antenna to an outdoor wireless bridge rated to handle extreme cold. So far, what I'm trying to decide is whether LMR-400 or LMR-600 series compatible cable is best suited for my application, or if it matters/are other options. I need 100-125FT in length. Will I experience substantial signal loss at these lengths?

Thank you guys so much for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert, and my experience is quite old and did not need to cope with extreme temperatures. Assuming you are running 802.11 (or 2.4 gig gear), you will experience substantial loss over cable that length.

You might want to try this calculator (a random one which I found on the Internet) - http://www.arrg.us/pages/Loss-Calc.htm - It showed about 2.3dB more loss using LMR400, which of-course translates to a marked difference on the power output.

If I recall for maximum power, we used LMR600 on runs over 30 feet when doing this stuff 15 years ago.